Populate results based on stacked data set
I wanted to filter the agents from the stacked column dataset A3:A26 to my table C3:F7.

My problem is how can I filter them easily using only the headers on my table from C2:F2, and my dataset only contain 1 column stacked together with the name of the agents and the name of the team leaders.

Perfect job for the WRAPCOLS() try: =WRAPCOLS(A3:A26,6)

If you don't have WRAPCOLS(), you can use this formula to determine starting/ending rows of the ranges: =IF(C2="",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/(ROW($A:$A)>B3)/($A:$A=""),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=C$2),COUNTIF($C$2:C$2,C$2))). Assuming you are placing the first formula in cell C3 (and D3, E3, F3, etc), you can the use this formula in cell C4 to get the list: =IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&C$3+1&":"&"A"&D$3-1),ROWS($C$4:C4)),"").

Basic alternative of WRAPCOLS() --> =IFERROR(IF(ROW(A1)>6,"",INDEX($A$3:$A$26,  ROW(A1)+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*6)), "") fill right and fill down!

Yes @EvilBlueMonkey, I am actually looking for it to be dynamic as the structure on the dataset is not always the same, the count of rows, count of agents and team leaders are subject to change at anytime, so I am looking for something to make this dynamic.

How do you determine whether a person is Team Leader or Agent, I dont think in practical world scenario, you will be having Team Leader1, Team Leader2,etc and then Agent1 Agent2 etc. ? Let me know that.

@MayukhBhattacharya  that's one of my challenges, I manually determine the name of the team leaders based on the spreadsheet being given to me. And this is how their data structure looks like, everyone is stacked up in a single column. I would only know the name of the Team Leaders based on their updated roster. I can maybe create a helper column and use xlookup to determine if a name on the next column is a leader or not.

Hi, Harvey, I am not posting it as an answer by reopening the post. Because it will not be fair to do such thing for the sake of posting an answer based on new updates, first of all, it was duplicate post, secondly because of the reason i have sighted in my last commentthen the post would have closed. Therefore, i commenting here, this should definitely work for you. =LET(_Data, A2:A24,_XLOOKUP, XLOOKUP(A2:A24,L3:L6,L3:L6,NA()),_TLs, SCAN(,_XLOOKUP,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(ISNA(c),r,c))), _Uniq, UNIQUE(TOROW(_XLOOKUP,2),1),IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",_Uniq, LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,FILTER(_Data,_TLs=b)))),,1),""))

@Harvey let me know if that works for you?

I'm sorry if I am already double posting, it has been few months since I asked this related question as I stopped working on that project, but it's now back recently and now I forgot that I might have asked the same question before and didn't noticed it. Sure will do! I will let you know if this one works. Thanks!

I can post an excel file in the comments, if that helps you to follow?

Sure! If that's not a problem, it would be a greater help to see the actual excel file with the formula!

Here you go,Excel
